# Подскажите аналоги JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Раньше пользовался JQuery, но сейчас заметил, что им всё реже пользуются. Подскажите с помощью каких технологий можно выполнить такие же задачи, делать всё вручную просто тоже не хочется.

Comment: От него избавляются по причине его тяжеловесности и аналогов ему нет, все больше сайтов просто уходят на ванильный javascript. Как мне кажется перед тем как писать на Jquery желательно уметь все это уметь писать на обычном JS

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Я понял, большое спасибо за отличный ответ.

Comment: я с jQuery ушел на angular 2+. А вы можете посмотреть в сторону реакта, например.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

У JQuery нет идентичных аналогов в своей нише. Все другие библиотеки могут выполнять схожие задачи, но их общее предназначение может сильно варьироваться. Для простых сайтов с минимальным количеством интерактива сегодня уже незачем притягивать JQuery, так как нативный JS уже умеет делать большую часть того, что умеет JQuery в контексте манипулирования элементами DOM. Тем не менее, в общем случае, на нативном JS вам придется писать больше кода, по сравнению с тем, что в JQuery можно сделать в одну строчку. С другой стороны, при ипользовании JQuery вы неизбежно столкнетесь с множественной конвертацией нативных элементов DOM в JQuery-объект и обратно.

На сегодняшний день одна из основных задач JQuery - кросс-браузерность отошла на второй план (по причине того, что браузеры стали лучше поддерживать стандарты). Задача JQuery сегодня - это манипуляция DOM, namespace-события, и крайне удобная обертка модулей js-анимации и ajax как Deferred объектов. Все это можно реализовать на нативном JS, но зачем? Далеко не каждый программист сможет сходу сделать все это лучше, чем это сделано в JQuery. И не все анимации можно сделать средствами чистого CSS.

Кроме того, нельзя не отметить очень важное преимущество JQuery по сравнению с нативным JS - это парадигма цепочечных вызовов, позволяющая писать более компактный код. А также тот факт, что на сегодняшний день существуют килотонны плагинов на JQuery, которые еще не переписаны на нативный JS.

Вывод такой, в простейших случаях, можно обойтись без JQuery (соответсвенно не тянуть в проект большой js для пары функций). Для больших интерактивных сайтов, вам возможно понадобятся более комплексные решения, нежели JQuery.

Если вам НУЖЕН и ДОСТАТОЧЕН функционал JQuery (DOM-манипуляция, js-анимации, ajax, deferred, пара-тройка готовых виджетов или плагинов), например для быстрого создания какого-нибудь Landing-page или маркетингового сайта, то почему бы его не использовать. И не даром слоганом библиотеки является: "пиши меньше, делай больше".

Answer (score 0):

YUI library.

YUI - это бесплатная библиотека JavaScript и CSS с открытым исходным кодом для создания интерактивных веб-приложений.

https://github.com/yui/yui3/wiki/Quick-Start.

Comment: Библиотека YUI не поддерживается активно с августа 2014 года и считается устаревшей (последний на данный момент релиз 3.18.1 был опубликован 22 октября 2014). Об этом есть соответствующая заметка на главной странице офф. сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь, чтоб не писать велосипеды cash-dom или dom7 они очень мало весят.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/802727)

Answer (score 0):

Можно jQuery заменить на что-то полегче, например Zepto.js. По размерам он меньше раза в 3. Основной функционал такой, же как и у jQuery. Может её заменять т.к. имеет идентичное API.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).