# Отказ от использования jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

На данный момент, уже множество вещей можно реализовывать на чистом javascript, без использования jquery.
Хотел бы отказаться во всех проектах от его использования, какие в данной ситуации есть за и против.

Comment: _"множество вещей можно реализовывать на чистом javascript"_ Да вы что? А раньше нельзя было? Интересно, а что тогда использовал jQuery? Может С++?

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: jQuery появился не потому что что-то нельзя было реализовать на нативном JavaScript. Собственно, jQuery это библиотека JavaScript-а, она написана на нем. Поэтому на нативном JavaScript-е можно реализовать все и даже больше. Проблема в том, что раньше [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) и [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM) в разных браузерах сильно отличался. jQuery была создана для того, чтобы избавиться от этой головной боли.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144861/Подскажите-аналоги-jquery/1145634

Comment: jQuery работает на том же уровне, что и DOM API; код несколько короче, но это не принципиально; Важно другое: они меняют **документ-модель**, который браузер отображает в картинку. Если посмотреть на многие задачи (как карзинка, список дел, или калькулятор), модель у них другая (товары, дела). И удобно работать с этой моделью, и отображать ее в документ (для отображения можно использовать React или аналоги). Подумайте, что в ваший задачах является моделью.

Comment: @notaProgrammer Я понимаю о важности и желании вставить пять копеек, но пораскинув серым веществом, можно понять, что речь ведется об удобстве и краткости, о том что jquery позволял скрестить и облегчить, работу с DOM.  Что вы написали в следующем комментарии. К чему первоначальные "рофлы"

Comment: @ZhyvkoRoman благодарю за ссылочку, ей вы дали полностью ответ на мой вопрос, о том, что jquery более не имеет необходимости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сходу  можно найти некоторые плюсы и минусы.

**Что есть против:**

- Если проект не использует все функции JQuery, то ненужный код может весить много.
- JQuery может не поддерживать некоторые технологии (например, `Canvas API`). Приходится подключать ещё библиотеки (`JCanvas`), что весит ещё больше.
- JQuery медленнее обычного кода на JS

**Что есть за:**

- JQuery стандартизует многие вещи и работает практически везде.
- Для JQuery написано огромное число плагинов, найти те которые работают без JQuery гораздо труднее.
- При использовании JQuery код короче

Тут уж сами можете решать, какие плюсы/минусы для вас важнее.